# What is the best way to structure my database tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm having trouble designing my database schema.
I am having doubts on whether to separate or group tables.

I have a blog and a News section in my application and database. Both receive Comments and Likes.

```
TABLE.BLOG | TABLE.COMMENTS.BLOG | TABLE.LIKE.BLOG
TABLE.NEWS | TABLE.COMMENTS.NEWS | TABLE.LIKE.NEWS
```

I share everything?

```
TABLE.BLOG | TABLE.NEWS
TABLE.COMMENTS | TABLE.LIKE
```

or should I keep comments grouped?

In case I should have some kind of reference type blog | news?

I am very confused about the best way to structure the database.
I really appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the exact layout depends mostly on the way that you are going to access and use your data, you are probably going to be better off with comments and likes sitting in the same table. Your second approach is close, although I would probably introduce a third table, called `CONTENT`, with an ID of anything that could be liked or commented.

Each row in the `NEWS` and the `BLOG` table would have a corresponding row in the `CONTENT` table. A `CONTENT` row could correspond to either a `NEWS` or a `BLOG`, but not both. `CONTENT` table has attributes common to blogs and news (date, title, author, and so on).

The `LIKE` and `COMMENT` tables would then be connected to the `CONTENT` table, so you would not need to duplicate these two tables for `NEWS` and for `BLOG`.

Here is an illustration:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: been interested in the explanation, but I fear I have not understood... could you give me another example? thank you

Comment: (a) Clarify your requirements. (b) This design assumes Blog & News are different, have different fields and different roles regarding other parts of the system (say news authors get paid but not blog writers). What they do have in common is content that gets "liked" and commented. Fields on Content table might be date_published_, body_text_, status_ (draft or published), and such. Content is child to Blog or News, Like & Comment are children to Content. Learn to read an [ERD diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–relationship_model), though that diagram's symbols are not exactly correct.

Comment: **@dasblinkenlight**, thanks for the picture! many fields are the same for both as NEWS BLOG, so I've been thinking about keeping a 'content table' with the fields that are equal for all content (text id, title, body, timestamp, likes ...) and in a separate table fields that are just NEWS (agency, author) and BLOG (collaborator published) ... so I keep centralized all content that is text and can be 'like' and commented ... this line is safe or'm talking a lot of nonsense? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Best is subjective, though I'd have two tables:

```
Content  (news and blog content, store like count)
Comment  (news and blog comments)
```

and then add a type field on both that distinguishes between blog and news.  That way you can reuse a lot of the db code.

IOW, minimize the number of tables if you can.

Comment: and in case you need to include one more field news, a field would be used to mara NEWS BLOG content and would have left the field, right? it brings not matter?

Comment: I'm thinking the content table would have fields like: id, contenttype, title, body, datecreated, author, and so on.  The Comment table might have fields like id, contentid, comment, datecreated.  You can check out Wordpress for an example of very simple database layout for a CMS.

Comment: ok, I understand, but if for some reason you need NEWS have an extra field that BLOG? when I register a NEWS it occupies all the fields and when I register a new BLOG POST a new field had been NULL. This approach is new to me, is it safe? thank you

Comment: Well, if there are a lot of differences, it might be better as two tables.  Though blog and news are very similar IMO.  I'd try to generalize the fields to be relevant to both types of article, or create another table Metadata that has fields like:  id, contentid, key, value.  Then you can attach free form data (or even serialized) data to an article.  You can also serialize all the special data (like using JSON) and store it in one field -- if the data does not need to be searchable.

Comment: IOW, basically all I'm doing is describing how Wordpress does it.  There's more than one way to do it, though it's easy to end up with a hundred tables otherwise.

Comment: I can have the table 'content' fields that are basic and common, like "id, title, body, timestamp, author..." and keep in a separate table fields that would be complementary: **complement.blog[fieldA, fieldB]** and **complement.news [fieldA, fieldB]** that would be used respectively as needed this is a good practice? thank you

Comment: yes, that would also work.  I've moved away from normalized database design a bit.  My current view is -- if you don't need to search something, or do math on it, serialize it as something like JSON (for a CMS at least).  Then you could also have a field Meta in the content table for free form data.